# required android.app.Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. But, it's asking me to use `android.app.Fragment` that I can't. How can I resolve below issue:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    private void requestCameraPermission() {
       --> if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
           --> new ConfirmationDialog().show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        } else {
            FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
}
```

> ERROR: Found: com.example.app.CameraFragment, required android.app.Fragment

```
public static class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final android.app.Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(R.string.request_permission)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(parent,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Activity activity = parent.getActivity();
                                if (activity != null) {
                                    activity.finish();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for method `show` inside `ConfirmationDialog.class`

Comment: @VenomVendor: Updated the question.

Comment: Change the import `import android.app.DialogFragment;` to `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;`

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the v4 support lib you shouldn't need `FragmentCompat`:

```
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
```

If that method isn't available, you might need to update your build.gradle to a new version of the v4 support lib.

Comment: How about this? `new ConfirmationDialog().show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);` I am still getting error on this line.

Comment: I think @VenomVendor's comment will solve that. Thanks. It's working now.